# hot module replacement dosen't work well with my webpack

Tags: linux, windows, reactjs, webpack

I developed my project with webpack and run it successfully. And I run `node build/webpack.dev.js --hot` in my command line in out development environment, it works well in linux os. But when I modyfied my source code in sublime text3 in windows os, the webpack didn't recompile the code, nethier did the chrome browser refresh it's page. However, when I used the `vim` commond to modify the code in the linux os. It works well. I can't figure out a way to solve this problem. Here are my code in `webpack.dev.js`:

```
new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  hot: hot,
  inline: true,
  compress: true,
  quiet: true,
  stats: {
    chunks: false,
    children: false,
    colors: true
  },
  historyApiFallback: true,
}).listen(PORT, HOST, function() {
console.log(localPublicPath);
});
```

Anybody who can help me?

Comment: What's the error you are seeing?

Comment: No error. When I saved the modified code, the webpack doesn't recompile automatically. I think that the hot module doesn't work.

Comment: There is no error in the commind line and the browser.

Comment: Have you enabled `atomic_save`  in Sublime? That can cause problems with watching files. It is recommended to disable it by the webpack docs [Adjusting Your Text Editor](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#adjusting-your-text-editor).

Comment: I used Sublime text3. So I disabled my atomic_save and set it to false like this `"atomic_save": false`, but it still doesn't work.